# How to make "python -m flask run" run main function?

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I'm working with a flask app that's currently launched as follows:

The starting command is `python -m flask run`, where `FLASK_APP` pointing to `__init.py__`.

`__init.py__` simply sets a variable `app` to an instance of `Flask`:

```
from .app import get_app

app = get_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # do nothing
    pass
```

It seems to me that flask detects global instances of `Flask` set in this module and runs them, even though I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Now I'd like to integrate Flask-SocketIO, which requires the flask app to be wrapped and the socket instance to be run.
From the docs, it seems that I should be able to run it from main:

```
from .app import get_app

app, sio = get_app() # returns a Flask and a SocketIO instance now

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sio.run(app)
    print("Flask-SocketIO server launched")
```

But I never see the expected output, and the socket server doesn't seem to be running. To me, this sounds like flask is ignoring the main function and still just launching any `Flask` instance it finds.

Why is this happening, i.e. is there any documentation on this? Or, am I doing the Flask-SocketIO integration wrong?

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__"` will only be executed when you execute that file, not when you import it from somewhere else. `python -m flask` looks for a variable called `app` or `application` or for a flask object. Is there a reason why you don't launch via `python mymainfile.py`?

Comment: That makes sense to me. Flask-SocketIO's docs have a [short paragraph on `flask run`](http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#initialization), but I don't understand how it's supposed to work exactly. The launch code is executed from a rather complex Node script I didn't create, but I can't see the motivation of that over `python x.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Flask 0.11 and the new cli, then all you need to do to run your application is `flask run`. Flask-SocketIO overrides the implementation of this command and adds the necessary magic to make everything work.

And you can remove your `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, unless you also want to be able to start the server using the old pre-Flask 0.11 way.

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing piece! I didn't see anywhere in the docs that `flask run` is actually changed by Flask-SocketIO. Also, that explains why a previous flag (`--with-threads`) suddenly stopped working. By any chance, do you happen to know where this flag is documented, as I couldn't find it either...

Comment: @CedricReichenbach To make Flask-SocketIO work with the Flask server, there are some restrictions that need to be imposed. In particular, while Flask gives you an option to use `--with-threads` on a regular server, when using Flask-SocketIO that option is not available. Flask-SocketIO requires threads to be enabled, so the option was removed and threads are enabled internally.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks a lot!